# replace string and douple spaces in string with special characters

Tags: java

I have two input strings:

```
"123  ABC"
"123  456 789 ABC"
```

My target is if in a string spaces between words are more than 1, then the spaces should be replaced with `-` else `,`

So output should be like this

```
"123-ABC"
"123-456,789,ABC"
```

I have googled so many posts and blogs but could not find any approach I could understand and apply for the same.

One post I've found where it was written that "Count the number of words. If it's greater than 2, replace all of then by dash, else by comma."

How we replace the spaces with `-`  and `,` with count of words?

Might be am thinking wrong.
Can anyone help me how to do it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Shouldn't you say *one or more* instead of *more than one*?. I presume that you want even a *single space* to be replaced*.

Comment: If space between two words is one that space should be replaced with "," and if its greater than one than it should be replaced with "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replaced = yourString.replaceAll(" {2,}", "-").replace(' ', ',');
```

`replaceAll` is using regex which allows us to write 2 or more as `{2,}`.

Rest of single spaces can be replaced with simple `char` replacement `replace(' ', ',')`.

<sub>I am assuming that all spaces are somehow surrounded by words and are not placed at start or end of your string. If my assumption is wrong let me know.</sub>